# Captura de angulação

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou fazendo um projeto que consiste em capturar a angulação do movimento utilizando o celular. As angulações já foram calculadas e estão funcionando. O problema que estou tendo é com a seguinte proposta:

> Dado que um paciente irá tirar a angulação do movimento do braço e queira iniciar a angulação de qualquer ângulo em 0 a partir de um click de um botão.

- **como poderia modificar meu código para obedecer a essa regra?**

**Exemplo**: o sensor está na posição de 270 graus e, ao paciente levantar o braço, a marcação irá estar em 0 graus. Ou seja, ele fez um movimento de 90 graus. Porém ao apertar o botão na angulação em 270 graus, deverá ser medido 0 graus até 90 graus, ao levantar o braço.

Os dados deverão ser sempre mostrados em tela, logo não é possível somente aplicar uma subtração.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ac = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = ac.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    ac.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    acceleration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acceleration);
    anguloZerado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.angulozerado);
    zeraAngulo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.zeraAngulacao);
}

 public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    acceleration.setText("X: " + sensorEvent.values[0] +
            "\nY: " + sensorEvent.values[1] +
            "\nZ: " + sensorEvent.values[2]);
    float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
    float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
    angle =  (float)((float) Math.atan2(x, y)/ (Math.PI/180));

    angle = ((angle + 360) % 360) + 90; //resolve o problema de -180 a -1 e conserta a angulação dos quadrantes
    str_angle = Float.toString(angle);
    angulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.angulo);
    angulation.setText(str_angle);

    zeraAngulo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            angulo2 = (float)((float) Math.atan2(x, y)/ (Math.PI/180));
            angulo2 = (((((angulo2 + 360) % 360) + 90) - angulo2) + 360) %360; //resolve o problema de -180 a -1
            str_zeraAngulo = Float.toString(angle);

            anguloZerado.setText(str_zeraAngulo);


        }
    });
    angulo2 = (((((angulo2 + 360) % 360) + 90) - angulo2) + 360) %360; //erro
    str_zeraAngulo = Float.toString(angulo2);
    anguloZerado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.angulozerado);
    anguloZerado.setText(str_zeraAngulo);
}
```

Comment: O `angulo2` já armazena o ponto de inicio não? Se sim você só precisa pegar o valor calculado do ângulo atual e fazer uma subtração simples + 360 `angle = ((angle + 360 - angulo2) % 360); `

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu acho que pensei em tantas coisas complicadas que escapei do mais básico. ¬¬